# Extract specific format from excel

Tags: excel, vba

I quite literally have no experience in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) and am relying on ancient Java knowledge

I have data in the format below and i want to extract 001-222-170 component (from line 1 etc)

```
TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,001-222-170,TEXT    
LINER,612-942-001,TEXT    
TEXT,TEXT17,612-551-001,TEXT   
SHOE,435-687-204,TEXT    
TEXT,ASSY,O.B,632-005-202,TEXT    
TEXT,TEXT,I.B,632-012-202,TEXT
```

After extensive research I know you have to set up a `.pattern` recognition. Closest thing I have is

```
Sub RegEx()
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Dim strTest As String
    Dim valid As Boolean
    Dim Matches As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    'What I happen to be looking for    
    RegEx.Pattern = "MT\d{6}V\d"

    For i = 2 To 115
        Range("B" & i).Activate
        strTest = ActiveCell.Text
        valid = RegEx.test(strTest)
        If valid = True Then
            Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(strTest)
            Range("C" & i).Value = CStr(Matches(0))
        Else
            Range("C" & i).Value = "#N/A#"
        End If
    Next

    Set RegEx = Nothing
End Sub
```

But it still does not do the trick plus I know there is a shorter way to do this. I just don't know how to format the pattern line. Something like  `("(\d)"-"(\d)"-"(\d)")` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
RegEx.Pattern = "\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{3}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below dumps the RegExp UDF to C2:C115 in a single shot (no loops) to run on B2:b115 respectively

Your regexp can be shortened to
`(\d{3}\-){2}\d{3}"`

```
Sub DumpReg()
    Range("C2:115").FormulaR1C1 = "=EXTRACT1(RC[-1])"
End Sub

Function Extract1(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim objRegMC As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Pattern = "(\d{3}\-){2}\d{3}"
        If .test(strIn) Then
            Set objRegMC = .Execute(strIn)
            Extract1 = objRegMC(0)
        Else
            Extract1 = "#N/A#"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is always in XXX-XXX-XXX format that you need, you can do this write on the spreadsheet without VBA or RegEx.

[image: Example]

**UPDATE VBA SOLUTION**

Here is a simpler VBA solution as well, without RegExp.

N.B. - This solution assumes there will not be any other instances of "-" in the cell text pattern, other than the XXX-XX-XXX pattern.

```
Sub dude()

Dim strTest As String

For i = 2 To 115

    strTest = Range("A" & i).Text

    If InStr(1, strText, "-") > 0 Then
        Range("C" & i) = Mid(strTest, InStr(1, strText, "-") - 3, 11)
    Else
        Range("C" & i) = "#N/A#"
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Just in case the first "-" isn't part of the telephone number you can revise that formula slightly to search for "-???-" where ? is any character, i.e. `=MID(A1,SEARCH("-???-",A1)-3,11)`

Comment: Great! If this answer is satisfactory, please mark it as accepted so others can more easily benefit from it in the future.

Comment: However now when i drag down the cells the copying of excell cells does not increment defeating the purpose of it being done bulk. Do i need to adjust some settings?

Comment: make sure your cell reference for `A1` says only `A1` and not `$A$1` - this involves absolute `$A$1` vs. relative `A1` cell referencing.

Comment: This is too general. Using `LIKE` would be superior

Answer (score 0):

A pattern you could use is: `\d+-\d+-\d+`  .  `\d+` simply means one or more decimal.
The sub could be written as:

```
Sub RegEx()
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Dim strTest As String
    Dim valid As Boolean
    Dim Matches As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    RegEx.Pattern = "\d+-\d+-\d+"

    For i = 2 To 115
        strTest = Range("B" & i).Text
        Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(strTest)
        If Matches.Count > 0 Then
            Cells(i, "C").Value = CStr(Matches(0))
        Else
            Cells(i, "C").Value = "#N/A#"
        End If
    Next

    Set RegEx = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent now how do i declare it as a function because i have no idea what a sub is?

Comment: By the way you can add a reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` and you can get some intellisense support for that Regex object.

Comment: a sub (subroutine) is like a void function, you've already used it in your example. But if you mean you need another format that returns a certain value, what would be the required setup?

Comment: I was looking to use it as a function inside excell so i can filter though a file. Can i use it as a function?

Comment: That pattern is too general. It will take any length of numbers rather than specifying 3. @user1475109 see my post that combines a UDF with a range dump

Comment: @brettdj True enough, but I hadn't made the assumption yet that the data would always be so strict. Judging by other answers, it is and in that case the other answers, such as the string split or Scott's answer, would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your format is gonna be the same and you want a VBA solution then Regex is an Overkill for this kind of thing. Here is a simple way using `SPLIT()`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim MyAr() As String, strSample As String

    strSample = "TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,001-222-170,TEXT"
    'strSample = "LINER,612-942-001,TEXT"

    MyAr = Split(strSample, ",")

    Debug.Print MyAr(UBound(MyAr) - 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: That is why I mentioned in my post that `If your format is gonna be the same` as it is same for all sample as the moment :) If the format is not the same then the above solution doesn't apply :)